# Hibernate - LIKE expression for case insensitive fitering

Tags: hibernate, filtering, sql-like

How can I use LIKE expression for case insensitive filtering in hibernate?

The corresponding entry in my hibernate file is:

```
<filter name="applicantNameFilter" condition="first_name LIKE :nameFilter"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<filter name="applicantNameFilter" condition="first_name ILIKE :nameFilter"/>
```

or

```
<filter name="applicantNameFilter" condition="UPPER(first_name) LIKE UPPER(:nameFilter)"/>
```

For Reference

1. Using ILIKE:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE textfield ILIKE 'value%';
   ```
2. Using Regexp operators (see Functions and Operators in the docs):

   ```
   SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE textfield ~* 'value';
   ```
3. Using UPPER() or LOWER() to change the case of the field before comparison; 
   this approach can be better than 1) or 2) because these functions may be 
   indexed, and thus if you are doing a "begins with" or "exact match" search 
   your query may be indexed:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE UPPER(textfield) LIKE (UPPER('value') || '%');
   ```
4. If most of your searches are "anywhere in field" searches on large text 
   fields, I'd reccomend a look at the two "full text search" tools available in 
   PostgreSQL, one in the /contrib of your source, the second from openFTS.org.

This is java code

User criteria as

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("first_name", first_name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
criteria.list();
```

Comment: Now I get the following error. My eclipse console..
        `this_.first_name this_.ILIKE ? 
        and this_.short_list_flag=? 
        and user4_.user_id=?
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query ....... Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "this_"
  Position: 3314`

Comment: replace ? with actual values and try to execute this query in postgres console directly.

Comment: I am very new to hibernate. And I dont know where to put this. Where has to apply the third option you given

Comment: something like this  <filter name="applicantNameFilter" condition="UPPER(first_name) LIKE UPPER(:nameFilter)"/>

Comment: Did you tried this? I tried these two. But not working. As you answered, for this I did not changed anywhere else. With my code filter is working in case sensitive mode. But when I put this, the application causess error in these two options.

Comment: What is your generated SQL with these 2 options ?

Comment: I got it by ilike in java side. thanks `criteria.add(Expression.ilike("firstName", extjsFilter.getValue(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `~*` instead of `LIKE`. The former does case-insensitive pattern matching (and is PostgreSQL specific).

For more info, see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE

Comment: <filter name="applicantNameFilter" condition="first_name :nameFilter"/>   I tried with this. But did not work.